# How to merge two json file using rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am trying to build a Document by loading two json files. The file loaded last takes the highest priority. 
In the example below `item1.value1` from `file B` overwrites the value from `file A`.  `item1.value2` `item2` does not exist in `file A` so the final Document just takes values from `file B`
file A:

```
{
level1: {
      level2: {
               item1: {
                       value1: 20,
                      }
              }
}
```

file B:

```
{
   level1: {
         item2{
               value1: 50
               value2: 60,        
               }
       level2: {
            item1:{
                       value1: 40
                       value2: 30,
       }
  }
}
```

my goal:

```
{
   level1: {
      item2{
            value1: 50
            value2: 60,        
      }
       level2: {
            item1: {
                       value1: 40,
                       value2: 30,
       }
  }
}
```

Another question when I am using the range for to iterate through the Document, only `level1` members are iterated, how can I go through the entire DOM?

```
for (auto& m : document.GetObject())
    printf("Type of member %s is %s\n",
        m.name.GetString(), kTypeNames[m.value.GetType()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above implementation assume that `srcObject` and `dstObject` share the same memory because it passes the original values instead of copying them.
This means that `dstObject` will hold freed objects when `srcObject` is freed.

I've implemented it by copying the values:

```
bool mergeObjects(rapidjson::Value &dstObject, rapidjson::Value &srcObject, rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType &allocator)
{
    for (auto srcIt = srcObject.MemberBegin(); srcIt != srcObject.MemberEnd(); ++srcIt)
    {
        auto dstIt = dstObject.FindMember(srcIt->name);
        if (dstIt == dstObject.MemberEnd())
        {
            rapidjson::Value dstName ;
            dstName.CopyFrom(srcIt->name, allocator);
            rapidjson::Value dstVal ;
            dstVal.CopyFrom(srcIt->value, allocator) ;

            dstObject.AddMember(dstName, dstVal, allocator);

            dstName.CopyFrom(srcIt->name, allocator);
            dstIt = dstObject.FindMember(dstName);
            if (dstIt == dstObject.MemberEnd())
                return false ;
        }
        else
        {
            auto srcT = srcIt->value.GetType() ;
            auto dstT = dstIt->value.GetType() ;
            if(srcT != dstT)
                return false ;

            if (srcIt->value.IsArray())
            {
                for (auto arrayIt = srcIt->value.Begin(); arrayIt != srcIt->value.End(); ++arrayIt)
                {
                    rapidjson::Value dstVal ;
                    dstVal.CopyFrom(*arrayIt, allocator) ;
                    dstIt->value.PushBack(dstVal, allocator);
                }
            }
            else if (srcIt->value.IsObject())
            {
                if(!mergeObjects(dstIt->value, srcIt->value, allocator))
                    return false ;
            }
            else
            {
                dstIt->value.CopyFrom(srcIt->value, allocator) ;
            }
        }
    }

    return true ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would try this (works for me):

```
void mergeObjects(rapidjson::Value &dstObject, rapidjson::Value &srcObject, rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType &allocator)
{
    for (auto srcIt = srcObject.MemberBegin(); srcIt != srcObject.MemberEnd(); ++srcIt)
    {
        auto dstIt = dstObject.FindMember(srcIt->name);
        if (dstIt != dstObject.MemberEnd())
        {
            assert(srcIt->value.GetType() == dstIt->value.GetType());
            if (srcIt->value.IsArray())
            {
                for (auto arrayIt = srcIt->value.Begin(); arrayIt != srcIt->value.End(); ++arrayIt)
                {
                    dstIt->value.PushBack(*arrayIt, allocator);
                }
            }
            else if (srcIt->value.IsObject())
            {
                mergeObjects(dstIt->value, srcIt->value, allocator);
            }
            else
            {
                dstIt->value = srcIt->value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dstObject.AddMember(srcIt->name, srcIt->value, allocator);
        }
    }
}
//...
rapidjson::Document from;
rapidjson::Document to;
mergeObjects(to, from, to.GetAllocator());
```

Note, types of nodes have to be equal. It additionally merges arrays by concatenating, not replacing.

You can iterate over entire DOM model using recursion (as above).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Be careful `mergeObjects` will move the children of `srcObject` to `dstObject`. After call this function, `from` will be an empty object.